# Create an array of band names where the pixel value is 1 in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, image, time-series, array

I have an image in GEE with 20 bands, each corresponding to one year. Indeed, I have a time series. Each band can have values 1, 0, or -1. Value 1 means a specific event starts, and value -1 means the previous event finishes. I aim to map when those events start and end for each pixel in the image. The particularity is that there can be several events for one pixel. Here is an example of the values of one pixel in the image:

> changes: Image (20 bands) 2003: 0 2004: 0 2005: 1 2006: 0 2007: 0
> 2008: 0 2009: 0 2010: -1 2011: 0 2012: 0 2013: 0 2014: 1 2015: 0 2016: -1
> 2017: 1 2018: -1 2019: 0 2020: 0 2021: 0 2022: 0

We see the first event, which started in 2005 and finished in 2010; the second event, which started in 2014 and finished in 2016; and the third, which began in 2017 and finished in 2018.

To tackle this, first, I want to be able to extract for each pixel the years when the events started, so the years when the pixel value is 1. Then, I will do the same for pixels with value -1.

I have to store this information in an array, but I am unfamiliar with it. Is this the best way to do so?

I tried this code, but it is not working; I get this error "*List (Error) String: Unable to convert object to string*":

```
 // Get the band names
var bandNames = cambios.bandNames();

// Create an array of band indices where the pixel value is 1
var bandIndices = ee.List.sequence(0, bandNames.length().subtract(1))
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq(cambios, 1));

// Map over the band indices and get the corresponding band names
var bandNamesArray = bandIndices.map(function(index) {
  return bandNames.get(index);
});

// Print the band names array
print('Band Names Array:', bandNamesArray);
```

How can I visualize the Array? is there a way to visualize it as an image?

Comment: See this blog post: https://medium.com/google-earth/runs-with-arrays-400de937510a

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproducible example of your code? It might be easier to help that way.